# Formula of an ellipse-like curve with custom skew and min/max points

Tags: geometry, functions, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, analytic-functions

I need to figure out the formula for a function of one variable x that looks like an ellipse, but I have control on points:

- min $x = A$
- max $x = B$
- the point $x'$ that curve attains its maximum value (If symmetric, this should be $(B+A)/2$)
- the max value of $f$ at $x'$

So I found this plot that is close to what I am trying to figure out. I tried to use the entropy function but I don't have control over what I need

*EDIT: please ignore my mistake on first plot ( correct is (A+B)/2) thanks Blue*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI: The $x$ value half-way between $A$ and $B$ should be $(A+B)/2$. (The distance from that point to the endpoints is $(B-A)/2$.)

Comment: true, my bad, thanks

Comment: Do you want to preserve vertical tangents in $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: Not really @jean Maria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=(C,H)$ be the "summit" of your graphical representation.

As suggested by your figures, one can consider two "quarter of ellipses" connected in $S$ using the common equation :

$$\dfrac{(x-C)^2}{L(x)^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{H^2}=1 \ \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ \ y=H\sqrt{1-\dfrac{(x-C)^2}{L(x)^2}}$$

with

where semi-axis $L$ is in fact (according to the region)

$$L(x)=\begin{cases}C-A& \ (x<C)\\B-C& \ (x \geq C)\end{cases},$$

a step function that can be written under the following compact expression using the "sign" function :

$$L(x)=\frac12\left[(B-A)+(2C-A-B)\text{sign}(C-x)\right]$$

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Varying $C$ while maintaining $H$ constant.*

Comment: I am not sure I follow the notation here, what is C and what is H

Comment: $C$ is the abscissa and $H$ the ordinate of the max. point of the curve. For example for the leftmost curve, $C=-0.5$ and $H=2$.

Comment: I should have maybe used lowercase letters instead of capitals (that can be confused with points)